# unable to create new application in Spinnaker AWS Demo setup

Tags: spinnaker

I'm trying to evaluate spinnaker on AWS.

I followed the document to setup VPC in AWS. I'm able to run Spinnaker at http://localhost:9000, but when I click on the new application in the Spinnaker UI, I see this error on the terminal.

`channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused.`

I'm unable to create a new application.

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday. I did following and after that I was able to create the application, 1) Make sure AWS is enable in config file /opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver.yml . Some thing like this, **aws:
  enabled: true**  2) Add the 127.0.0.1:8084 in SSH tunnel if you have started your spinnaker  with localhost. I did the above two things other than what mention in document and was able to access and bake the AMI.

Comment: I enabled AWS in clouddriver.yml file and restarted spinnaker but still no use. I couldn't create an application. Spinnaker documentation is not really helpful to evaluate in AWS.

Comment: Have you found any solution? @Anudeep

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that port 8084 is blocked. The Spinnaker UI(Deck) needs to be able to communicate with the API(Gate) over port 8084.

In AWS, try opening port 8084, same way you did for port 9000.